# How to use Images in Xamarin.Forms UWP?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm currently creating a sample system in Xamarin.Forms UWP. I'm wondering why does my codes to call an image doesn't seem to work properly in the UWP part while it is working in Android. I also want to set an image as a background and an image as a button.

How can I code this so that it will function properly on both platforms?

Here is the code I've used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.LoginPage"
         BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg"
         Title="MainPage">
  <Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
             Padding="40">
    <Image Source="ebmslogo1.png"/>

    <StackLayout Padding="0,50,0,0">

      <Entry x:Name="txtUserName"
             Placeholder="Username"
             x:Hint="Username"
             BackgroundColor="Black"
             TextColor="White"/>

  <Entry x:Name="txtPassword"
         Placeholder="Password"
         IsPassword="true"
         BackgroundColor="Black"
         TextColor="White"/>

      <Button Text="LOG IN"
          FontSize="14"
         BackgroundColor="Teal"
         Clicked="NavigateButton_OnClicked"/>

    </StackLayout>

  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

My images are located in **.Droid > Resources > drawable**

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Xamarin Forms in UWP the images must in the root project directory (not in Assets) and build action set to Content.

Images will then work as they do in Android and iOS in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Oh I see. But what codes do I need to use? Can I use this code?  <Image Source=filename.png"/>

Comment: Yes, if you have the image just as a string e.g. <Image Source="image.png" /> then if you place that image in drawable (on Android), root project (on Windows), Resources (on iOS) then it will show correctly in Xamarin Forms on all 3 platforms.

Comment: I've already tried this Sir,  **<Image Source=filename.png"/>** but it didn't worked. I don't know why :(

Comment: Do you have 2 quotation marks in your code?, I noticed you only have one at the end, every time you mention filename.png"

Comment: Oh I'm sorry Sir. Yes it has 2 quotation marks, but it still didn't worked. I've added it on the Assets folder on my UWP and didn't display anything.

Comment: Did you add it to the root project directory of the UWP app. So adding directly to the UWP project and not any folder underneath it. Also for UWP try adding the WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" to the Image tag, I think it might need them.

Comment: Where can I find the root directory project Sir?

Comment: Just right click on SampleUWP > Add > Existing Item

Comment: Oohh. That seems to be the answer. I thought I need to  add an existing item under the ASSETS folder. Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: i have 1 Question.. how can we add images directly to root.then what about folder stucture.. if i have lots of images and other folders.then it will be mess.isnt ot?

Comment: Yes it is a mess :) The only way around it if you wanted to use a folder is to put a ValueConverter on each image source and change the URL for any images on UWP/WinRT

Answer (score 5):

For UWP Xamarin forms:

1. Create Folder named "scale-100" in the root then put all your images in it.
2. Specify image name with extension ex: `<Image Source="myimage.png"/>`

You can also create "scale-xxx" as specified from this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/images-tailored-for-scale-theme-contrast#qualify-an-image-resource-for-scale-theme-and-contrast)

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder Named Resources in UWP project, put images there with Content as build Action

[image: resource folder]

Then use this MarkupExtension

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace XamarinFormsMoshCourse.MarkupExtensions
{
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Source))]
    public class PlatformResourceImageExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Source)) return null;

            string imageSource = String.Empty;

            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    {
                        imageSource = Source;
                        break;
                    }
                case Device.Android:
                    {
                        imageSource = Source;
                        break;
                    }
                case Device.UWP:
                    {
                        imageSource = String.Concat("Resources/", Source);
                        break;
                    }
            }
            return ImageSource.FromFile(imageSource);
        }
    }
}
```

add markup extensions foler as xaml namespace and use like this

```
     <Button ImageSource="{local:PlatformResourceImage clock.png}"/>
        <Image Source="{local:PlatformResourceImage clock.png}"/>
```

now you can use the same syntax with the same image path on all platforms

[image: UWP]
[image: XamarinFormsPrewiew Android Demo]

Answer (score 2):

You can create a folder and use a [Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) to change path, like this:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Image), typeof(CustomImageRenderer))]

public class CustomImageRenderer : ImageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
    {
        if(e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var source = e.NewElement.Source;
            if(source is FileImageSource fileImageSource)
            {
                fileImageSource.File = $"Assets/{fileImageSource.File}";
            }
        }      
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you need to use image in uwp and android so here my solution :

1. Declare image in xaml

```html
<Image x:Name="kitty"/>
```

2. add a "Resources" folder in pcl project
3. add a "Images" folder in "Resources"
4. paste image and go to image property (rigth click>property)
5. change "build Action" to "Embedded resource ([microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2019))
6. add this in you page code :

```js
kitty.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("stackoverflow.Resources.Images.kitty.png", typeof(MainPage).Assembly);
```

Advantage :

- you can use the same image multiple time and don't need a copy in each project

Disavantage :

- don't know if you can use it in a MVVM project

if you just want to use you uwp project and not another just add a folder to "Assets" and make you xaml source like this

```html
<Image x:Name="kitty" Source="Assets/Images/kitty.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In UWP you can use

`img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png"));`

The images are located in the Assets folder as per the below screenshot

[image]